# Configure BIND and DNSMasq to work together on the same machine

Tags: linux, dns, port-forwarding, bind, dnsmasq

I have prepared a setup, where both **BIND9** and **DNSMASQ** are installed on my machine.

The DNS traffic goes to the port **53** where the main DNS server (BIND) handles the requests, checks the data and decides​ what to reply to the client based on it's RPZ zones policies.

All other requests are forwared to an external DNS server **and everything works fine until this part**.

---

Also, I have installed **DNSMASQ** on port **5353**.

My configuration inside bind was changed to something like:

**named.conf.options**

```
[...]

 forwarders { 127.0.0.1 5353 5353; };

[...]
```

This should be the correct syntax to tell BIND to forward all the traffic to the **127.0.0.1 port 5353**, however this isn't working for some reason.

I have also found another similar discussion ( https://serverfault.com/questions/430269/recursive-forward-a-zone-in-bind ) about the topic but the request is slighly different and I **can't use another ip** to do the same job as the other user do!

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you attach all your bind configuration files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [bind9 documentation](http://www.bind9.net/arm910.pdf), the proper syntax is:

```
forwarders { 127.0.0.1 port 5353; };
```

As for using another IP, I'm not sure this is necessary, but I'd like to mention that you have plenty of IPs in the 127.x.x.x range. Just bind bind9 on 127.0.0.1:53 and dnsmasq on 127.0.0.2:53 for example.

Comment: I was using the wrong syntax seemingly haha thanks!